# TypeError 'Item' subject is no iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to associate **Categories** with **Subjects** and their description.

As I understand the error in `items.html`. I tried using for to display categories on the site that have a link to objects, but they describe them, but I got this error and don’t understand how to solve it.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from shop.models import Category, Item, Comment
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, HttpResponse

def mainpage(request):
    categorys = Category.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'shop/mainpage.html', {'categs':categorys})

def items(request, categ_id):
    try:
        itemss = Item.objects.get(id = categ_id)
    except:
        raise Http404("Not found")

    return render(request, 'shop/items.html', {'itemss':itemss})

def info(request, item_id):
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(id = item_id)
    except:
        raise Http404("No one item is no found")

    return render(request, 'shop/info.html', {"item":item})
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Категория"
        verbose_name_plural = "Категории"

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = "Unknown")
    item_desc = models.TextField(default = "Empty")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = 0)
    quanty = models.CharField(max_length = 10000, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + "  "

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Предмет"
        verbose_name_plural = "Предметы"

class Comment(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique = True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(default = "Empty")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name + "  "

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Комментарий"
        verbose_name_plural = "Комментарии"
```

**mainpage.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}TradeWithUs{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
    {% if categs %}
        {% for categ in categs %}
            <a href = "{% url 'shop:items' categ.id %}">{{categ.name}}</a></br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        No one category was found ):
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**items.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}TradeWithUs{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
    {% if itemss %}
        {% for iteme in itemss %}
            <a href = "{% url 'shop:info' iteme.id %}">{{iteme.name}}</a></br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        No one item was found ):
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**info.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{item.name}}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h2><p class="names">{{item.name}}</p></h2>
    <p class="description">{{item.item_desc}}</p>
    <p class = "numbers">Price {{item.price}} ║ Total  {{item.quanty}}</p>
    <hr>
    <em>{{item.publish_date}}</em>  <em>@all rights reserved</em>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

Here is the whole mistake.

I don’t understand why such an error occurred here, because before creating the categories, objects by reference translated to their description, but as soon as I added the categories, this error appeared

```
File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\NewSite\Newsite\Newsite\apps\shop\views.py", line 10, in items
    itemss = Item.objects.list(id = categ_id)
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'list'
[01/Jun/2020 13:24:28] "GET /mainpage/item_1 HTTP/1.1" 500 67313
Internal Server Error: /mainpage/item_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\NewSite\Newsite\Newsite\apps\shop\views.py", line 10, in items
    itemss = Item.objects.list(id = categ_id)
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'list'
[01/Jun/2020 13:26:57] "GET /mainpage/item_1 HTTP/1.1" 500 67313
C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\NewSite\Newsite\Newsite\apps\shop\views.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 01, 2020 - 13:27:03
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'Newsite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /mainpage/item_1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\Desktop\NewSite\Newsite\Newsite\apps\shop\views.py", line 15, in items
    return render(request, 'shop/items.html', {'itemss':itemss})
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 165, in render
    values = list(values)
TypeError: 'Item' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
 itemss = Item.objects.get(id = categ_id)
```

This is a single Item, and as such not iterable, so when you pass it to `itemss` and try and do this in the template:

```
{% for iteme in itemss %}
```

You get the resulting error.

If you want to use only one item, lose the `for` loop. If You sometimes want to have multiple items in here and are using this template from other places as welll, then maybe instead of the `get`, use a `filter` - that should return an iterable for you.